# How to edit XML file in R {XML}

Tags: xml, r

I have seen some similar threads on this, but none that seem to answer my questions exactly:

I have an XML file of a building with several "Space" objects.  I'm trying to replace the "ID" attribute of the Space with the "Name" value under the space.  For a simplified example:

```
<Space zoneIdRef="idref text"  id="id text">
    ...
    ...
    ...
     <Name>"name text"</Name>
</Space>
```

So I want to end up with Space id="name text" instead of "id text".

What I have tried so far:

```
rm(list = ls())

file = "C://Users//ben.brannon//Desktop//Project1.xml"
outfile = "C://Users//ben.brannon//Desktop//Project1_new.xml"

xml = xmlTreeParse(file)
root = xmlRoot(xml)

n=4

for (i in 3:3+n-1)
{
  name = xmlSApply(root[["Campus"]][["Building"]][[i]][["Name"]],xmlValue)
  spaceattrs = xmlAttrs(root[["Campus"]][["Building"]][[i]])

}

saveXML(root, outfile)
```

When I check the new values in "root" within R, it seems to have updated correctly, but when I write the file, they haven't been changed. I'm wondering if there's a better way to update the value than just with an "=", or maybe I'm not dealing with the text  strings correctly?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure with `for (i in 3:3+n-1)`? Shouldn't it be `for (i in 3:(3+n-1))`? The first expression evaluates to 6, while the second to 3:6.

Comment: That's it!  Just a silly little mistake but it's working now - thanks nicola!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple assignment should suffice.

XML:

```
<Root>
    <Campus>
        <Building>
            <Space zoneIdRef="idref text"  id="id text">
                <Name>"name text"</Name>
            </Space>
        </Building>
    </Campus>
</Root>
```

Code:

```
library(XML)

xml <- xmlTreeParse("XML.xml")
root = xmlRoot(xml)
name = xmlValue(root[["Campus"]][["Building"]][["Space"]][["Name"]])

xmlAttrs(root[["Campus"]][["Building"]][["Space"]])[["id"]] <- name
```

Comment: That's much simpler, but the "id" in the file I'm writing out still doesn't seem to reflect any changes (though I can see the changes in the R workspace).

Comment: Actual, this was answered in comment to my question above.